Invalid transaction on parachain with lookahead collator
I just did a upgrade of polkadot-sdk from 1.1.0 to stable2407, and enabled async-backing according to this article.
It looks fine at the beginning: blocks are produced at 6s and submitting tx manually works. However, it meets problems in our CI where an off-chain worker constant sends tx to parachain and some of these tx are reported as invalid.
Network setup:

local network launched with zombienet (config)
no delayed-best-block in ParachainImport
lookahead aura consensus
for other runtime setting, please see this lib.rs

The our CI, the worker constructs the extrinsics offline and sends them to parentchain without waiting for any InBlock or Finalized status.
Example log below.
By searching for extrinsic hash 97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80 we can see it's firstly imported as ready and then reported as invalid, without specifying the reason.
It seems to cause subsequent tx to be blocked too (or in future queue).
Questions are:

is the random invalid tx normal under async backing? (I had the impression that this could come from the frequent re-org in the local testnet)
if I'm doing something wrong (e.g. when constructing extrinsics), how to go further and find it out? I have -l=parachain=debug,txpool=trace,runtime=debug,import_queue=debug as log level already
how to mitigate this / make it more reliable in both local test and real network? We have another service that relies on the parachain tx submitted from the worker, yet we couldn't wait for the finalisation in the worker itself (due to time constraints)

What I also found is this is not necessarily related to async-backing, but rather lookahead consensus - it could be mitigated by delayed-best-block use. Such problem didn't happen with old (v1.1.0) setup.
Some other issues that might be related:

How to solve this invalid block issue after sending a Transaction?
Debugging transaction Fails with `Status: Invalid`

2024-12-15 17:40:42.033  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 19. Hash now 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc, previously 0x6380d7ec9706d77efe611b60d12bbc98bac912f118c1b1a595fc61b07ec83242.
2024-12-15 17:40:42.034  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Imported #19 (0x46ec…8787 → 0x4f19…81fc)    
2024-12-15 17:40:42.034  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.255859375kb, extrinsics: 3.6591796875kb, storage_proof: 9.384765625kb }
2024-12-15 17:40:42.034  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 7.9580078125kb
2024-12-15 17:40:42.035 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collation-generation: [Relaychain] candidate is generated candidate_hash=0x35694171b9e89d6028c283c1bfe393777aaeb8b4741cb09bc4a6a4002fd94ad6 pov_hash=0xaf19aa2141aaa24ee3c174008032f88519e101d15c46098bb01c7236a03b4e8e relay_parent=0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb para_id=2106 traceID=70995602313689240427806909019428459383
2024-12-15 17:40:42.035 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Received session info session_index=3
2024-12-15 17:40:42.035 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Accepted collation, connecting to validators. para_id=2106 candidate_relay_parent=0x6555…5bcb relay_parent_mode=Enabled { max_candidate_depth: 3, allowed_ancestry_len: 2 } candidate_hash=0x35694171b9e89d6028c283c1bfe393777aaeb8b4741cb09bc4a6a4002fd94ad6 pov_hash=0xaf19aa2141aaa24ee3c174008032f88519e101d15c46098bb01c7236a03b4e8e core=CoreIndex(0) current_validators=[Public(8eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a48 (5FHneW46...))] traceID=70995602313689240427806909019428459383
2024-12-15 17:40:42.035 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Advertising collation. relay_parent=0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb candidate_hash=0x35694171b9e89d6028c283c1bfe393777aaeb8b4741cb09bc4a6a4002fd94ad6 peer_id=12D3KooWRkZhiRhsqmrQ28rt73K7V3aCBpqKrLGSXmZ99PTcTZby traceID=70995602313689240427806909019428459383
2024-12-15 17:40:42.035 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators request peer_set=Collation requested=1 failed_to_resolve=0
2024-12-15 17:40:42.035 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Collation num_peers=1 removed=0
2024-12-15 17:40:42.148 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80] WaitingTransaction { imported_at: Instant { tv_sec: 26899186, tv_nsec: 722569434 }, transaction: Transaction { hash: 0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80, priority: 1354, valid_till: 20, bytes: 175, propagate: true, source: TransactionSource::External, requires: [], provides: [9e66b40bb21cc1612ba3275966d418832157238b05d48b7126ad966b87f0c99c02000000], data: 84009e66b40bb21cc1612ba3275966d418832157238b05d48b7126ad966b87f0c99c00c50a4d20e31b2c82ff3178c4d219fa751397dd8de1e815e9eff4e1257c17af9cbd7fa7ccc0c24b15c75e49438b964e5c03bf97f9b8e4c86ac3ff4455763db40a520008005d15313e14ae56db46c321b9db35411b16f527b7effcd62a77c601ba6ddf39c6adbb0d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}, missing_tags: {}}    
2024-12-15 17:40:42.148 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80] Importing to ready    
2024-12-15 17:40:42.148 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80] Ready (replaced with None)    
2024-12-15 17:40:42.148 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: Pool Status: PoolStatus { ready: 1, ready_bytes: 175, future: 0, future_bytes: 0 }    
2024-12-15 17:40:43.180  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (2 peers), best: #31 (0x6555…5bcb), finalized #28 (0x62a1…de34), ⬇ 1.6kiB/s ⬆ 4.3kiB/s    
2024-12-15 17:40:43.183  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #19 (0xc8aa…67db), finalized #14 (0xd0b2…a3c1), ⬇ 31 B/s ⬆ 33 B/s    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.320 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] resolve hash: 0x91024186013ec3634fd23a76865c374aa2e771eb3e50bd16da46b9e9da3f4ad7 finalized: true tree_route: (common HashAndNumber { number: 29, hash: 0x91024186013ec3634fd23a76865c374aa2e771eb3e50bd16da46b9e9da3f4ad7 }, last Some(HashAndNumber { number: 29, hash: 0x91024186013ec3634fd23a76865c374aa2e771eb3e50bd16da46b9e9da3f4ad7 })) best_block: 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb finalized_block:0x62a1b8367d3f3d616d384ffa9feb23046f62fab03edd523a5222000fe57ade34    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.320 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] handle_enactment: no newly enacted blocks since recent best block    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.320 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] on-finalized enacted: [], previously finalized: 0x62a1b8367d3f3d616d384ffa9feb23046f62fab03edd523a5222000fe57ade34    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.320 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Attempting to notify watchers of finalization for 0x9102…4ad7    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.320 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] [0x6d0ff2a40d68bc755f2cd11cdea0a84b15bc6b3fa55f05bb34443568ab01beaf] Sent finalization event (block 0x91024186013ec3634fd23a76865c374aa2e771eb3e50bd16da46b9e9da3f4ad7)    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.320 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] [0x70605ee9fe63d3b7b51c4d640c801aad888c995d2031778053d831c3b909511b] Sent finalization event (block 0x91024186013ec3634fd23a76865c374aa2e771eb3e50bd16da46b9e9da3f4ad7)    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.320 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] resolve hash: 0xfb601ac00bfbf18f51b4770c8a9d30e12654412baf61813e9dbf4612b8cf5ba7 finalized: true tree_route: (common HashAndNumber { number: 15, hash: 0xfb601ac00bfbf18f51b4770c8a9d30e12654412baf61813e9dbf4612b8cf5ba7 }, last Some(HashAndNumber { number: 15, hash: 0xfb601ac00bfbf18f51b4770c8a9d30e12654412baf61813e9dbf4612b8cf5ba7 })) best_block: 0xc8aaa77191f05f2d6eebc19b543fefce0d1992476cd422154ef5e8f474b767db finalized_block:0xd0b26498dbb4c6f794bee1d742b179768a7035e343302afafa08d2e3dd1fa3c1    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.321 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] handle_enactment: no newly enacted blocks since recent best block    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.321 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] on-finalized enacted: [], previously finalized: 0xd0b26498dbb4c6f794bee1d742b179768a7035e343302afafa08d2e3dd1fa3c1    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.321 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Attempting to notify watchers of finalization for 0xfb60…5ba7    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.321 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0xd16443fff2ff8bda908c2c5ce81ba4266095c17630fa10e2ef556de945b216d0] Sent finalization event (block 0xfb601ac00bfbf18f51b4770c8a9d30e12654412baf61813e9dbf4612b8cf5ba7)    
2024-12-15 17:40:44.321 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x88e4537402a916d3a05de59a348fc11077c739fd674816f8ef99b917e567453c] Sent finalization event (block 0xfb601ac00bfbf18f51b4770c8a9d30e12654412baf61813e9dbf4612b8cf5ba7)    
2024-12-15 17:40:46.016 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators request peer_set=Collation requested=1 failed_to_resolve=0
2024-12-15 17:40:46.016 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Collation num_peers=1 removed=0
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::mmr::offchain: [Relaychain] offchain db set: pos 57 parent_hash 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb key [12, 109, 109, 114, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 85, 114, 38, 166, 169, 109, 178, 33, 62, 179, 17, 52, 214, 65, 28, 43, 71, 193, 25, 112, 248, 176, 221, 89, 8, 169, 215, 51, 125, 91, 203]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::mmr::offchain: [Relaychain] offchain db set: pos 58 parent_hash 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb key [12, 109, 109, 114, 58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 85, 114, 38, 166, 169, 109, 178, 33, 62, 179, 17, 52, 214, 65, 28, 43, 71, 193, 25, 112, 248, 176, 221, 89, 8, 169, 215, 51, 125, 91, 203]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::mmr::offchain: [Relaychain] offchain db set: pos 59 parent_hash 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb key [12, 109, 109, 114, 59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 85, 114, 38, 166, 169, 109, 178, 33, 62, 179, 17, 52, 214, 65, 28, 43, 71, 193, 25, 112, 248, 176, 221, 89, 8, 169, 215, 51, 125, 91, 203]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::mmr::offchain: [Relaychain] offchain db set: pos 60 parent_hash 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb key [12, 109, 109, 114, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 85, 114, 38, 166, 169, 109, 178, 33, 62, 179, 17, 52, 214, 65, 28, 43, 71, 193, 25, 112, 248, 176, 221, 89, 8, 169, 215, 51, 125, 91, 203]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::mmr::offchain: [Relaychain] offchain db set: pos 61 parent_hash 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb key [12, 109, 109, 114, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 85, 114, 38, 166, 169, 109, 178, 33, 62, 179, 17, 52, 214, 65, 28, 43, 71, 193, 25, 112, 248, 176, 221, 89, 8, 169, 215, 51, 125, 91, 203]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::mmr::offchain: [Relaychain] offchain db set: pos 62 parent_hash 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb key [12, 109, 109, 114, 62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 85, 114, 38, 166, 169, 109, 178, 33, 62, 179, 17, 52, 214, 65, 28, 43, 71, 193, 25, 112, 248, 176, 221, 89, 8, 169, 215, 51, 125, 91, 203]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] [process_inherent_data] bitfields.len(): 2, backed_candidates.len(): 1, disputes.len() 0    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] Size before filter: 778, candidates + bitfields: 777, disputes: 1    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] Time weight before filter: 8569167896, candidates + bitfields: 8569167896, disputes: 0    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] Max block weight: Weight(ref_time: 2000000000000, proof_size: 18446744073709551615)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] Used max block time weight: Weight(ref_time: 2000000000000, proof_size: 18446744073709551615)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] Used max block size: 5242880    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] Used max block weight: Weight(ref_time: 2000000000000, proof_size: 5242880)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.013 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::parachains::scheduler: [Relaychain] [occupied] now_occupied {<wasm:stripped>: <wasm:stripped>}    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.013 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::system: [Relaychain] [32] 2 extrinsics, length: 1416 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight:Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) op weight Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) / mandatory weight Weight(ref_time: 11847299459, proof_size: 54644) (0%)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] resolve hash: 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b finalized: false tree_route: (common HashAndNumber { number: 31, hash: 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb }, last Some(HashAndNumber { number: 32, hash: 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b })) best_block: 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb finalized_block:0x91024186013ec3634fd23a76865c374aa2e771eb3e50bd16da46b9e9da3f4ad7    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Imported #32 (0x6555…5bcb → 0x32d8…cc5b)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] handle_enactment tree_route: TreeRoute { route: [HashAndNumber { number: 31, hash: 0x65557226a6a96db2213eb31134d6411c2b47c11970f8b0dd5908a9d7337d5bcb }, HashAndNumber { number: 32, hash: 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b }], pivot: 0 }    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Pruning transactions: [0x295b9c1b4539b10eaf673e68c49a951ce54056a40e3b9690cf2bb75852b82e66, 0xdfec45e1fd43c0ce209b684d950143ac3b55ea3afbe54f1121411f6ffd93409a]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Starting pruning of block 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b (extrinsics: 2)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Pruning at 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Pruning at 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b. Resubmitting transactions.    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] [0x295b9c1b4539b10eaf673e68c49a951ce54056a40e3b9690cf2bb75852b82e66] Pruned at 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.014 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] [0xdfec45e1fd43c0ce209b684d950143ac3b55ea3afbe54f1121411f6ffd93409a] Pruned at 0x32d81732cba100641e2c70f3f0ea08b305fe400aee75d00fd33b51aa6e35cc5b    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.015 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x91024186013ec3634fd23a76865c374aa2e771eb3e50bd16da46b9e9da3f4ad7
2024-12-15 17:40:48.015 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Collation was requested. candidate_hash=0x16de0da96407de4d8e90c87d5d1630fb926a3f1408b899ff291f3cf512e436d8 pov_hash=0x13ed8ab70e1647b056f6a69912580028eb0768b001997958cdd1dbae34524395 traceID=30395982901705206578709321338813034747
2024-12-15 17:40:48.018  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc (#19)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.019 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Transaction pool already processed block  #19    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.020 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80] Reported as invalid. Will skip sub-chains while iterating.    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.020 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Removing invalid transactions: [0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.020 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80] Removed as part of the subtree.    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.020 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Removed invalid transactions: [Transaction { hash: 0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80, priority: 1354, valid_till: 20, bytes: 175, propagate: true, source: TransactionSource::External, requires: [], provides: [9e66b40bb21cc1612ba3275966d418832157238b05d48b7126ad966b87f0c99c02000000], data: 84009e66b40bb21cc1612ba3275966d418832157238b05d48b7126ad966b87f0c99c00c50a4d20e31b2c82ff3178c4d219fa751397dd8de1e815e9eff4e1257c17af9cbd7fa7ccc0c24b15c75e49438b964e5c03bf97f9b8e4c86ac3ff4455763db40a520008005d15313e14ae56db46c321b9db35411b16f527b7effcd62a77c601ba6ddf39c6adbb0d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.020 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x97daa5f075d3510322b4f19dac6bae78092bbf69a2d81690091c4cbb16b48c80] Extrinsic invalid    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.020 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::system: [Parachain] [20] 2 extrinsics, length: 3746 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight:Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) op weight Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) / mandatory weight Weight(ref_time: 2037136694734, proof_size: 5888940) (0%)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.021  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 20 (2 ms) [hash: 0xe5785575979d11f889c4dff01b842e8b4e1aaf1120c6424a2e1747cd9c67cced; parent_hash: 0x4f19…81fc; extrinsics (2): [0xefb6…4346, 0x8daa…f8ee]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.022  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 20. Hash now 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68, previously 0xe5785575979d11f889c4dff01b842e8b4e1aaf1120c6424a2e1747cd9c67cced.
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_informant: [Parachain] ♻️  Reorg on #19,0xc8aa…67db to #20,0xc520…1b68, common ancestor #17,0x7640…3138    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Imported #20 (0x4f19…81fc → 0xc520…1b68)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] resolve hash: 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68 finalized: false tree_route: (common HashAndNumber { number: 17, hash: 0x76407f4cce0e16afd437278d1e798473c1f26574a3dbc15a2e1b41b61e213138 }, last Some(HashAndNumber { number: 20, hash: 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68 })) best_block: 0xc8aaa77191f05f2d6eebc19b543fefce0d1992476cd422154ef5e8f474b767db finalized_block:0xfb601ac00bfbf18f51b4770c8a9d30e12654412baf61813e9dbf4612b8cf5ba7    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] handle_enactment tree_route: TreeRoute { route: [HashAndNumber { number: 19, hash: 0xc8aaa77191f05f2d6eebc19b543fefce0d1992476cd422154ef5e8f474b767db }, HashAndNumber { number: 18, hash: 0x9d45134df78a4cd28486ebdf4870d6e73c0204df32acea16059a6da8ef1134c2 }, HashAndNumber { number: 17, hash: 0x76407f4cce0e16afd437278d1e798473c1f26574a3dbc15a2e1b41b61e213138 }, HashAndNumber { number: 18, hash: 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787 }, HashAndNumber { number: 19, hash: 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc }, HashAndNumber { number: 20, hash: 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68 }], pivot: 2 }    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning transactions: [0x72de916fe639f93f0f0e7f77331c5802ae94963307daf32c3731d625e8fb6ba5, 0xcef95e6b6b08f7d39b04af972c07ed9c17807b982dceac74db9f6ba2a18a17b6]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Starting pruning of block 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787 (extrinsics: 2)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning at 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning at 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787. Resubmitting transactions.    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x72de916fe639f93f0f0e7f77331c5802ae94963307daf32c3731d625e8fb6ba5] Pruned at 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0xcef95e6b6b08f7d39b04af972c07ed9c17807b982dceac74db9f6ba2a18a17b6] Pruned at 0x46eccaf495c9bad6df39c9a0dcc67701bb6be3499db983cadc86d43e65ff8787    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning transactions: [0x72de916fe639f93f0f0e7f77331c5802ae94963307daf32c3731d625e8fb6ba5, 0x5e127acaf65d036644404acc5e64bd5840fa567aa19d202a223253781baad623]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Starting pruning of block 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc (extrinsics: 2)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning at 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning at 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc. Resubmitting transactions.    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x72de916fe639f93f0f0e7f77331c5802ae94963307daf32c3731d625e8fb6ba5] Pruned at 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x5e127acaf65d036644404acc5e64bd5840fa567aa19d202a223253781baad623] Pruned at 0x4f195ee9558de59034224694af7919c35cac7790f3b3888a419d5e43778181fc    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning transactions: [0xefb67cb5d20f0b5d6fc07e61e1448930a7b4b073ff73db3e5d49bac5d6ba4346, 0x8daa21edcf8b5974b59565be8e3bd46b486c4b622000eb18114b6d08ca83f8ee]    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Starting pruning of block 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68 (extrinsics: 2)    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning at 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Pruning at 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68. Resubmitting transactions.    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0xefb67cb5d20f0b5d6fc07e61e1448930a7b4b073ff73db3e5d49bac5d6ba4346] Pruned at 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x8daa21edcf8b5974b59565be8e3bd46b486c4b622000eb18114b6d08ca83f8ee] Pruned at 0xc52051ebad853f7922d2b7628c59cf8694c9da6f69ea203e6ca7098d63541b68    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0xe8a85d4b49e0ef0afb48f6ba2d73da9281e8a0c847ca003b030f1ae09bda92eb]: Resubmitting from retracted block 0xc8aaa77191f05f2d6eebc19b543fefce0d1992476cd422154ef5e8f474b767db    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x11723807c54abb225eead7764a462eaf3782597426de79a6c4ded542e676ff98]: Resubmitting from retracted block 0xc8aaa77191f05f2d6eebc19b543fefce0d1992476cd422154ef5e8f474b767db    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x8cbb6c882d6bc741e6d1eb3707b488de2e0fe65adb1651c9d5fa1bc6f5febd68]: Resubmitting from retracted block 0xc8aaa77191f05f2d6eebc19b543fefce0d1992476cd422154ef5e8f474b767db    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x66b22c0c7ba6f1db00b29c00776bc60a8d4b51fd9217350bfe6b9483ccf60ece]: Resubmitting from retracted block 0x9d45134df78a4cd28486ebdf4870d6e73c0204df32acea16059a6da8ef1134c2    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x0d7558c10174d0d44236af17ff1c0fbbd5e55e7641662e4eaeeb074e2817874d]: Resubmitting from retracted block 0x9d45134df78a4cd28486ebdf4870d6e73c0204df32acea16059a6da8ef1134c2    
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.255859375kb, extrinsics: 3.6591796875kb, storage_proof: 10.173828125kb }
2024-12-15 17:40:48.023  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 8.9404296875kb


I edited the title, as I found that it wasn't necessarily related to async-backing, but rather lookahead collator.
The problem happens with or without async-backing

I got answers in https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/6915 , I expect it to be completely solved by fork-aware txpool.
For now I'll just use a workaround mentioned in https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/1202

You can mark this as the answer.
